# Conditioning the interceptor

Tags: angular

I have the following interceptor, which inserts the token to all the requests, but I want to be able to condition there that I insert the token only when the session is started, when it is not, that I do not insert it, some idea of how I could solve it?

```
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.auth.isAuthenticated$.subscribe((data) =>
      console.log("boolean", data)
    );
    return this.auth.getTokenSilently$().pipe(
      mergeMap((token) => {
        const tokenReq = req.clone({
          setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        });
        return next.handle(tokenReq);
      }),
      catchError((err) => throwError(err))
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
getTokenSilently$(options?): Observable<string> {
    return this.auth0Client$.pipe(
      concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.getTokenSilently(options)))
    );
  }
```

Comment: What is the auth.getTokenSilently doing? Can you please include the details?

Comment: @HugoNoro ready you add it in the question, "getTokenSilently$" what it does is get the token of the user who is logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
      mergeMap((authenticated: boolean) => {
        if (authenticated) {
          return this.auth.getTokenSilently$().pipe(
            mergeMap((token) => {
              const tokenReq = req.clone({
                setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
              });
              return next.handle(tokenReq);
            })
          );
        } else {
          return next.handle(req);
        }
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I think something like that could work for me, that code gives me an error in the if

Comment: Expression expected.

      if (authenticated) {

Comment: Try the edited code. I'm writting from mobile, so I've wrote some wrong code.

Comment: now I get this mistake here(Observable<HttpEvent<any>>):  A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

Comment: It was missing the outer return. Try again. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

To me seems quite expensive that you fetch the token on every request. Why are you not storing it in session/local storage or cookie or any similar mechanism?

By storing the token after login you now have a way of detecting when a user is logged in by simple checking if the token exists already on your side. If it does, append it to the request. If it doesn’t, don’t append.

There’s a bit more to it but I believe this can answer your use case.

Also you have the advantage of doing 1 less request per each request you do. The way you have now for each request you do you need to do an extra one to fetch the token.